# How to change extension by batch on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-extension

How to change extension by batch on Windows 10. For example I have thousands of *.JPG but I would like to have .jpg. Is there any software for that?

Comment: `ren *.JPG *.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following two commands in a Command Prompt:

```
cd path\to\the\root\folder
ren *.JPG *.jpg
for /d %x in (*) do pushd "%x" & ren *.JPG *.jpg & popd
```

Use the last command if you have sub-folders of the root folder that also
need to be processed.

As for Windows the extension `JPG` is the same as `jpg`, this code might be a bit
slower than absolutely required, but that shouldn't be a big problem.